# Metric spaces - sets proof

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space and $A\subset X$. Prove that $\partial A = \overline A \cap \overline{X \setminus A} $.
I have no idea how to prove that. Please help.

Comment: How is teh boundary defined?  As the closure less the interior?

Comment: Not every question including the word "set" is a question in set theory.

Comment: What definition of $\partial A$ are you using?  Have you solved other problems where you have to show that two sets are equal?

Comment: C'est vrai, Asaf.

Comment: My definition is that $\partial A$ is the set of all points all of whose neighborhoods meet both $A$ and $A^c$.

Comment: Yes, I have boundary defined as closure less the interior.

Comment: @user74200 I hope my answer is helpful.  It is hard to give an optimal answer when I don't know what you've proven before, e.g. if you know that $\partial A = \partial (X \setminus A)$.  Please comment my answer if anything is unclear or if you have any further difficulty.

Comment: Or you can do that by the definition of the boundary of a set

Answer (score 1):

To show two sets are equal, first assume we have an element of the first set, and show it is in the second set.  Then, assume we have an element of the second set, and show it is in the first.

Proof outline:

1. Let $x \in \partial A$ arbitrary.
   Show that $x \in \overline{A}$ (this should be easy from your definition).
   Then, show that $x \in \overline{X \setminus A}$ using the fact that $\partial A = \partial (X \setminus A)$.
2. Let $y \in \overline{A} \cap \overline{X \setminus A}$ arbitrary.
   Show that $y \in \partial A$ by showing that $y \in \overline{A}$ but $y \not \in \text{Int } A$.

Comment: "using the fact that $\partial A=\partial(X\setminus A)$": Also proving that fact, of course:)

Comment: @JonasMeyer certainly :)  See also my comment on the question itself.